# How many fresh peaches are equivalent to 20 ounces of frozen peaches?

Tags: fresh, peaches

I have fresh ripe peaches and plan to make a cobbler. The recipe calls for 20 ounces of frozen sliced peaches, how many fresh (medium sized) should I use?

Comment: In a cobbler, I'm not sure that you need to super accurate, but why wouldn't you use 20 ounces (or round up to the nearest whole peach)?  Do you have a scale? Or maybe your question is "how much does a medium sized peach (minus pit) weigh?

Comment: I'd say it's 1:1 (i.e. 20 for 20), assuming the frozen peaches are frozen from fresh, then there shouldn't be any water loss that might complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that you don't have a scale in your kitchen, (which for some reason is common in the USA, I grew up in a house like that) then get a quart measuring cup and hack up fresh peaches until you hit (or exceed, I agree with the comment) 2-1/2 cups - because 20 ounces by weight of frozen peaches is pretty near to 20 ounces by volume of fresh peaches and juice, if cut and packed so there's not much air space. If leaving air space it might be full quart of less packed down/cut up peaches.

Also, put a kitchen scale on your gift list for whatever gift giving occasions (including gifting yourself) might be coming up, and correct that situation.

If you have a scale, remove pits and weigh 20 ounces of pitted peaches.

How many medium peaches gets caught up in "what's a medium peach" but seems to be 4 according to one definition of "medium" (5.3 ounces, I'm going to guesstimate the pit as 0.3 so it works out, and I'd choose 5 to be sure there was plenty, since @mosjafj is correct in the comments. And pits might be heavier than that.)

Comment: You can get perfectly serviceable kitchen scales for about $10 on eBay (mine are as good as the ones I had before cost 3x that, except for being a little small so the display hides under big pans).  I'd hesitate to recommend just spending money, but honestly, they're worth having

Comment: I absolutely suggest, without hesitation, buying or getting a suitable scale, but that doesn't help with making a peach cobbler *right now.*